# Comparison of Mergesort & Quicksort with Linked List

Tags: list, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

After analyzing the time complexity of mergesort and quicksort on linked list, **my goal is to know how fast mergesort and quicksort is with linked list by experiment.** So I have my own implementation of the linked list and the two sorting algorithms **[here](https://gist.github.com/coperd/643db4292bacd32aceaa)** which I believe work *right* after many test cases.

**How do I do this:** In my case, I record the time using `clock_gettime()`(**with high resolution of nanoseconds**) before and after `mergesort()` and `quicksort()` and then calculate the time elapsed as the sorting time. For each generated list, I run sorting algorithms on it **`nt`** times to see the degree of time variance. Then comes the **odd results** below:

```
(1). Results on Linux
Size      Idx   MS Time        QS Time        Ratio(MS/QS)
512000    1     0.3281263960   0.2921808090   1.1230251471
512000    2     0.3289270020   0.7525636530   0.4370753234
512000    3     0.4738711210   0.7488168700   0.6328264493
512000    4     0.4718711760   0.7550283460   0.6249714709
512000    5     0.4752055230   0.7475322080   0.6356990614
512000    6     0.4719117050   0.7537721490   0.6260667837
512000    7     0.4756928710   0.7477671780   0.6361510441
512000    8     0.4739681430   0.7543113980   0.6283454608
512000    9     0.4740305430   0.7481235620   0.6336260039
512000    10    0.4742394170   0.7549861040   0.6281432393

Size      Idx   MS Time        QS Time        Ratio(MS/QS)
4096000   1     3.5476424790   2.6812770450   1.3231167162
4096000   2     3.5978723540   11.3582210030  0.3167637215
4096000   3     6.4508664680   12.1178579670  0.5323437926
4096000   4     7.5211969840   12.9918780050  0.5789153024
4096000   5     6.3990375720   15.0615052880  0.4248604273
4096000   6     6.7338463860   12.6689220030  0.5315248120
4096000   7     6.3984526790   13.0335491000  0.4909217459
4096000   8     6.3998418310   12.6702337620  0.5051084259
4096000   9     6.3992318020   12.6689156020  0.5051128292
4096000   10    6.3966458040   12.6710802350  0.5048224528 

(2). Results on Mac OS
Size      Idx   MS Time        QS Time        Ratio(MS/QS)
4096000   1     5.0670630000   3.7523430000   1.3503730869
4096000   2     5.3244930000   3.3779550000   1.5762474633
4096000   3     4.8768480000   3.6002920000   1.3545701293
4096000   4     4.7556650000   3.5490720000   1.3399742242
4096000   5     4.8412420000   3.5490860000   1.3640813438
4096000   6     4.7306100000   3.4840990000   1.3577714066
4096000   7     4.9213480000   3.5255380000   1.3959140421
4096000   8     5.0002410000   4.0561230000   1.2327636514
4096000   9     4.9949580000   3.7667090000   1.3260801405
4096000   10    5.0599200000   3.6623090000   1.3816201746
```

As showed above, for each row with the same `Size` value, it means they are the running results of linked lists with the same value. Be aware that, in my implementation, the linked list is reconstructed before the sorting and freed after, so the cache shouldn't blame.

**Question:** I run the test on two linux servers and got the similar results. When I run sorting on a linked list of size `Size`(e.g. 512000) for `nt`(e.g. 10) times, all the first results is different from the remaining nine ones. To be specific, the `quicksort` runs faster than `mergesort` in the first test case and loses badly in the following 9 tests. But the test results in Mac OS show that `quicksort` always outperforms `mergesort` when `Size` is big enough, which makes sense to me.

I also tried using `gettimeofday()` and other timers such as `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` to time, the result remains the same. **Can anyone explain why is the result on Linux like this?** For the `10` tests on the same list, the results should be quite the same, at least all showing that `quicksort()` is faster than `mergesort()` or vice vesa.

Comment: What is `sizeof (void*)` on both platforms? Also: what is `sizeof (struct node)` ?

Comment: @wildplasser Both Linux and Mac OS have  `sizeof(void *)` = 8 & `sizeof(struct node)` = 16.

Comment: Does `sizeof` matter? BTW, I updated my test scripts and also put the result file to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/coperd/643db4292bacd32aceaa). When `Size` is greater than ~6w, they all show that, on the same data set (list), the first test result is quite different from the following ones. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was thinking of alignment difference caused by different sizes. (not) inlining of static functions could also be a difference (the mergesort code looks terrible without inlining) . Check the compiler output and/or the profile.

Comment: Did you compile the program with the same optimization and debug flags on both systems?